# Uploaded multple images in canvas convert into one image(Html5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to convert canvas into one image. Right now i am using Html5 canvas and FebricJs for uploading multiple images.
code:

```
<style>
   canvas{
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
</style>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="file">
<script>
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
   document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
       var file = e.target.files[0];
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function (f) {
           var data = f.target.result;
           fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
               var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);
               canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
               var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
           });

       };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
       format: 'png',
       opacity: 0.9
   });
     console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);              
   });

</script>
```

My JSFiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/8gt6d7op/

But i want finally this canvas convert into one image. Because i want send final image to server.

Screen Shot:
[image]

Right now I am getting converted image of canvas but first time uploaded image not show in canvas image. Please see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/8gt6d7op/1/) for clarification. 
After upload image generate some base code of image in console, This base code paste in address bar then one image is missing. How to get final image of canvas.

Fabric.js library code link..https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/dist/fabric.js

Please share your idea to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *canvas.toDataURL* conversion

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'jpeg', quality: 0.8 });
```

needs to be done after the image is loaded. It's current placement is incorrect and so you will be getting an image uri that would be missing the last  added image.
Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sujitkm/p51zwL50/)

Comment: Well, when I first tested, this was working. But when I see now, this exhibits the same behavior as you have mentioned. So, you can ignore the answer if it doesn't work. Though the suggestion on moving the assignment of dataURL is correct.

Comment: Your answer absolutely correct, but one thing is remaining. After click browse Image then click on click me link as your mention in your JSfiddle, But last image set by default same place again and again. When i move last browse image in canvas.But it is taking by default same place. Thanks sujit

Answer (score 2):

According to Fabric.js documentation, the [Canvas.toDataURL](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDataURL) method should return a Base64 representation of the composed canvas.

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
  format: 'jpeg',
  quality: 0.8
});
```

At this point `dataURL` is a string which you can send back to the server.

Comment: Your answer is right, But in this case last image will not come. Please check base code in console.

Comment: You should see the image if you click on the data URI in the console. Instead of using console.log simply send the string to the server

Comment: I am doing somethink like that, Please check this JSFiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/8gt6d7op/1/